# boost unit test visual studio not showing in console

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, boost

I'm trying to setup a boost unit-test framework in my C++ solution inside Visual Studio 2010. Here below, I give you the code I use for the unit-test (well, the code I use while trying to understand how to make it work).

```
#define MAP_LOADER_TEST maploadertest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
using namespace boost::unit_test;

void my_test_function() {
    BOOST_CHECK(2 == 1);
}

test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    test_suite* test = BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "Master test suite" );

    test->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &my_test_function ) );

    return test;
}
// EOF
```

I can see with the breakpoint that it does run the unit-test, which is good. 
But I don't understand why it doesn't show the results of the tests in the output.

In ***Proj->Props->Linker->System->SubSystem*** I've given **/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE**

Could someone tell me what I'm missing to be able to see the tests' output in the console.

Thank you

Comment: how do u run the unit-test? I can get the output in my console.

Comment: I click the "green arrow" to play the application, in "Debug" mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the "green arrow" to play the application in "Debug" mode, the command prompt closes after the application exits. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or use the "Start without debugging" option, then you'll see the output.